# how to find the induced metric on an orbit?

Tags: lie-groups, dg.differential-geometry

Hi, Let $M$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $G$ a (Lie) subgroup of $Iso(M)$ which acts on $M$ smoothly and properly. Suppose we know the orbits up diffeomorphism. Is there a systematic way to recognize the induced metric on an orbit of the action?
you may assume that $M$ is a space form of constant curvature and and $G$ is compact or semisimple or ... if there is no acceptable answer in general case.
thanks to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The orbit is homogeneous, so it's enough to compute the metric at one point, call it $x$.  The map from the Lie algebra to the tangent space to the orbit at $x$ is surjective.  Concretely for a vector $X$ in the Lie algebra the corresponding tangent vector is $X_M (x) := d/dt \exp  (tX) \cdot x$ ( $\cdot $ denotes the action).  Now take another vector $Y$ in the Lie algebra and compute the inner product between $X_M (x)$  and $Y_M (x)$.  This computes the induced "metric" on $G/G_x$ ($G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$).  The word "metric" is in scary quotes because it could be zero.